# C++ CMake Library Structure

Tags: c++, cmake

## Description

I have the following Program (Minimum Example) consisting of 2 Libraries (build either as static or shared (DLL)) and an Executable which uses the two libraries.

### MyLib Library

The MyLib Library just had an Interface class and an Implementation of that Interface as shown below:

```cpp
//include/mylib/mylib.h
#pragma once
#include <string>

#include "export.hpp"

class MYLIB_EXPORT MyLib {
   public:
    virtual std::string name() const = 0;
    virtual ~MyLib();
};

---- 
//src/mylib.cpp

#include "mylib/mylib.h"

MyLib::~MyLib() = default;

---

//include/mylib/mylib_impl.h
#pragma once
#include "export.hpp"
#include "mylib.h"

class MYLIB_EXPORT MyLibImpl : public MyLib {
   public:
    virtual std::string name() const override;
    virtual ~MyLibImpl();
};

---

//src/mylib_impl.cpp
#include "mylib/mylib_impl.h"

#include "privlib.h"

std::string MyLibImpl::name() const {
    PrivLib privLib;
    return privLib.name();
}

MyLibImpl::~MyLibImpl() = default;

---

//src/privlib.h

#pragma once
#include <string>

class PrivLib {
   public:
    std::string name() const;
};

---

//src/privlib.cpp

#include "privlib.h"

std::string PrivLib::name() const {
    return "PrivLib";
}
```

### Consumer Library

The Consumer Library just uses the `MyLib` type and stores it in an shared pointer. It does not need the concrete implementation here.

```cpp
//include/consumer/consumer.hpp
#pragma once
#include <mylib/mylib.h>

#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "export.hpp"

class CONSUMER_EXPORT Consumer {
   public:
    Consumer(std::unique_ptr<MyLib> mylib);
    std::string data() const;

   private:
    std::unique_ptr<MyLib> myLib_;
};

---

//src/consumer.cpp

#include "consumer/consumer.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

Consumer::Consumer(std::unique_ptr<MyLib> mylib) : myLib_{std::move(mylib)} {
}

std::string Consumer::data() const {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "MyLib Name: ";
    ss << myLib_->name();
    return ss.str();
}
```

### Main

In the Main Method the `Consumer` is constructed with the concrete type of the `MyLib` Interface.

```cpp
//src/main.cpp
#include <consumer/consumer.h>
#include <mylib/mylib_impl.h>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    std::unique_ptr<MyLib> mylib = std::make_unique<MyLibImpl>();
    Consumer consumer{std::move(mylib)};
    std::cout << consumer.data() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

## Question

Now my question is regarding building the `MyLib` Library and linking the `Consumer` against it. Normally i would do something like the following:

```
#MyLib CMakeLists.txt

add_library(MyLib)

target_sources(MyLib PUBLIC "include/mylib/export.hpp"
                            "include/mylib/mylib.h"
                            "include/mylib/mylib_impl.h"
                     PRIVATE    "src/mylib.cpp"
                                "src/mylib_impl.cpp"
                                "src/privlib.h"
                                "src/privlib.cpp")
                                
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC 
                            "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
                            "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<INSTALL_PREFIX>/include>"
                            PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>")


set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES
                        PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADER_FILES}"
                        DEBUG_POSTFIX "d"
                        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
                        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
                        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)

if(MSVC)
    target_compile_options(MyLib PUBLIC /wd4251 /wd4275 PRIVATE /W4)
    set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/ignore:4099")
endif()

if(NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    string(TOUPPER MyLib PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)
    set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -D${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_STATIC)
endif()

include(GenerateExportHeader)
string(TOUPPER MyLib PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)
generate_export_header(MyLib
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/mylib/export.hpp
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_EXPORT
    STATIC_DEFINE ${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_STATIC
)

# Consumer CMakeLists.txt

add_library(Consumer)

target_link_libraries(Consumer PRIVATE MyLib)

target_sources(Consumer PUBLIC "include/consumer/consumer.h"
                                "include/consumer/export.hpp"
                                PRIVATE "src/consumer.cpp")

target_include_directories(Consumer PUBLIC 
                            "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
                            "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<INSTALL_PREFIX>/include>"
                            PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>")


set_target_properties(Consumer PROPERTIES
                        PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADER_FILES}"
                        DEBUG_POSTFIX "d"
                        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
                        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
                        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)

if(MSVC)
    target_compile_options(Consumer PUBLIC /wd4251 /wd4275 PRIVATE /W4)
    set_target_properties(Consumer PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/ignore:4099")
endif()

if(NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    string(TOUPPER Consumer PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)
    set_target_properties(Consumer PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -D${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_STATIC)
endif()

include(GenerateExportHeader)
string(TOUPPER Consumer PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)
generate_export_header(Consumer
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/consumer/export.hpp
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_EXPORT
    STATIC_DEFINE ${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_STATIC
)
```

Or would it be better to seperate the `MyLib` into two different Library? A Header Only (Interface) one with only the Headerfiles in it and then link the `Consumer` Library against this? Like shown here:

```
#MyLib CMakeLists.txt

add_library(MyLibAPI INTERFACE )
target_include_directories(MyLibAPI INTERFACE   "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
                                                "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<INSTALL_PREFIX>/include>")

add_library(MyLib)

target_sources(MyLib PUBLIC "include/mylib/export.hpp"
                     PRIVATE    "src/mylib.cpp"
                                "src/mylib_impl.cpp"
                                "src/privlib.h"
                                "src/privlib.cpp")
                                
target_link_libraries(MyLib PRIVATE MyLibAPI)

target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC 
                            "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
                            "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<INSTALL_PREFIX>/include>"
                            PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>")


set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES
                        PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADER_FILES}"
                        DEBUG_POSTFIX "d"
                        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
                        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
                        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)

if(MSVC)
    target_compile_options(MyLib PUBLIC /wd4251 /wd4275 PRIVATE /W4)
    set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/ignore:4099")
endif()

if(NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    string(TOUPPER MyLib PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)
    set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -D${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_STATIC)
endif()

include(GenerateExportHeader)
string(TOUPPER MyLib PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)
generate_export_header(MyLib
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/mylib/export.hpp
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_EXPORT
    STATIC_DEFINE ${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_STATIC
)

# Consumer CMakeLists.txt

add_library(Consumer)

target_link_libraries(Consumer PRIVATE MyLibAPI)

target_sources(Consumer PUBLIC "include/consumer/consumer.h"
                                "include/consumer/export.hpp"
                                PRIVATE "src/consumer.cpp")

target_include_directories(Consumer PUBLIC 
                            "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
                            "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<INSTALL_PREFIX>/include>"
                            PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>")


set_target_properties(Consumer PROPERTIES
                        PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADER_FILES}"
                        DEBUG_POSTFIX "d"
                        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
                        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
                        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)

if(MSVC)
    target_compile_options(Consumer PUBLIC /wd4251 /wd4275 PRIVATE /W4)
    set_target_properties(Consumer PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/ignore:4099")
endif()

if(NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    string(TOUPPER Consumer PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)
    set_target_properties(Consumer PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -D${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_STATIC)
endif()

include(GenerateExportHeader)
string(TOUPPER Consumer PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)
generate_export_header(Consumer
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/consumer/export.hpp
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_EXPORT
    STATIC_DEFINE ${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_STATIC
)
```

In that case i create the Interface Library `MyLibAPI` and link against it in the `Consumer`

I also put the Code on Github:

- ["Normal" Version](https://github.com/KevDi/DemoLib/tree/normal)
- [Split Version](https://github.com/KevDi/DemoLib)

### Second (maybe dumb) Question

If i change the `consumer.cpp` file like this:

```cpp
#include "consumer/consumer.h"

#include <mylib/mylib_impl.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

Consumer::Consumer(std::unique_ptr<MyLib> mylib) : myLib_{std::move(mylib)} {
}

std::string Consumer::data() const {
    MyLibImpl impl;
    std::cout << impl.name() << '\n';
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "MyLib Name: ";
    ss << myLib_->name();
    return ss.str();
}
```

so making a direct call to the `MyLibImpl` when the `Consumer` only links against the `MyLibAPI` the build failed when building as a shared Library which is what i was expecting.
Confusingly the build is successfull and the code runs when building as a static library. Could someone explain this?
[Not Working Part](https://github.com/KevDi/DemoLib/tree/non_working)

## Summary

1. Is it better to split the `MyLib` (`MyLibAPI` Interface and `MyLib` Library)?
2. Why does the build not failed when building as a static Library?

Comment: Stack Overflow is mainly about **fixing errors** in the code. If you have a **working code** and ask about ways for *improving* it, then [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for such questions. "Why does the build not failed when building as a static Library?" - You didn't show the error message which you get, but I guess it is "undefined reference" error which is emitted during the linking phase. Creation of a static library doesn't involve linking phase, so doesn't emit such errors.

Comment: @Tsyvarev and now the fun starts. Because I first posted it on Code Review. There they mentioned it is not the right place so I posted it here but this seems also be the wrong place so where should I post it?? The main question I have is should I split the library in a header only part for the headers (Interface) and the library part linking against it or should I better leave it as a single library

Comment: "... I first posted it on Code Review. There they mentioned it is not the right place ..." - Probably, because your question post has actually **two questions**? The second one - "Why does the build not failed when building as a static Library" - belongs here, but its answer is quite simple (I provided it in the first comment). But the other question - "Is it better to split the MyLib (MyLibAPI Interface and MyLib Library)?" - doesn't belong here, because, if the "splittied" variant works, it is up to you to decide which variant to choose. In short: ask a **single question** per question post.

Comment: ... Actually, I am not very familiar with rules of Code Review. It could be that they are specialized on improving a single variant and not on the choosing between several ones. But a question about choosing between two working variants is definitely not suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Would you please not recommend Code Review if you are unfamiliar with their scope? Example code (MCVE) is not accepted there.

Comment: @Mast, Sorry, I forgot about that aspect about your site (hypothetical code is prohibited). But otherwise my suggestion ("If you have a working code and ask about ways for improving it, then Code Review is a better place for such questions.") looks good, doesn't it? By the way, as you are expert on Code Review (I see you have a diamond on that site), could you shed a light on my previous comment - whether questions about choosing between working variants are on-topic on your site? (Assuming all other criteria of your site are fulfilled.)

Comment: I guess the main problem is that it is more a opinion based answer and therefore the question is also not valid for code review because there could be more opinions on that topic. I can also close the question here if you like.

Comment: @Tsyvarev We do have a [comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review?tab=Newest) tag which seems to fit what you suggest. It doesn't always work out and I'm sure there are still questions in there that should've been closed instead, but it can be done. It has to be actual code. Differences between Stack Overflow and Code Review can be found in [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/52915).

Comment: @Kevin: "I guess the main problem is that it is more a opinion based answer and therefore the question is also not valid for code review because there could be more opinions on that topic. " - Yes, it seems to be so. At least, for have objective reasons for choose one variant or another, we need more details about your purposes. Generally, the reasoning is simple: it is better to have as simple project structure as possible. But the simple variant could complicate some use cases. If those use cases are **really** bother you, then you have a point in defense of the more complex variant.